# disable textfield if other text fields depending on another field

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to disable one of my input field, if the vlue in   other text field is not '0'.I am not sure what is going wrong.Can you help.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
<script>
    var dis2 = document.getElementById("text2");
    text2.onchange = function () {
        if(this.value!= 0) {
            document.getElementById("text1").disabled = true;
        }
    }


</script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputText id="text1" label="Name" title="Name"/>
                <apex:inputText id="text2" label="Name2" title="Name2" onchange="foo(this);" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VF page you can't directly get the element by using`document.getElementById("text2");`. Instead use the $Component global variable to get the DOM elements.

Salesforce documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm

I have modified your code as below Using $Component global variable.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
    <apex:form id="theform" >
        <apex:pageBlock id="thepageblock" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="thepageblockscn" >
                <apex:inputText id="text1" label="Name" title="Name"/>
                <apex:inputText id="text2" label="Name2" title="Name2" onchange="foo(this);" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        var txt1 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.theform.thepageblock.thepageblockscn.text1}");
        var txt2 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.theform.thepageblock.thepageblockscn.text2}");
        txt2.onkeyup = function () {
            if(this.value!= 0) {
                txt1.disabled = true;
            }else{
                txt1.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```